# How to read multiple ASCII files in R

Tags: r, ascii

I'm trying to read multiple .asc files in R so I can perform some analyses later on them. I'm using this code:

```
library(raster)
list_file <- list.files ("C:\\Users\\Areej\\Documents\\Gibbon_bangladesh\\Bangladesh_Env_Vs_30s_ascii_R\\",
 pattern ".asc", full.names = T) 
gibbon <- stack(file_list)
gibbon
```

but it shows me *unexpected token* for the ".asc" part in the code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an `R` question than a ascii or even `{raster}` issue.
You wrote a badly defined pattern just as the error message responded.
You should have checked that you got a vector of filenames as a result for the second line of code.
This code should fix the pattern issue:

```
library(raster)
list_file <- list.files ("C:\\Users\\Areej\\Documents\\Gibbon_bangladesh\\Bangladesh_Env_Vs_30s_ascii_R\\",
 pattern = "*.asc", full.names = T) 
gibbon <- stack(file_list)
gibbon
```

Note that you were missing a star (`*`) so the pattern will include all files with the `.asc` extension.

You can also use this pattern to be certain that the file ends with `.asc`:

```
pattern = "\\.asc$"
```